# Is there a way to loop a char into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, types, char

To elaborate, what I mean is, if I wish to create an array of the alphabet:
(i.e. `char[] alphabet = new char[26];`)
is it possible to use a for loop, for instance, to iterate over chars as opposed to me initializing each letter individually in brackets?
(i.e. `char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c',...'z'};`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just add a value to a `char` in a loop. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = (char) ('a' + i);
}
```

Alternatively, `String.toCharArray()` like

```
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

Comment: I understand the second piece of code where the toCharArray method created a new character array from the string, but I do not understand why you casted char--or that's how I am interpreting it.  
Can you explain to me what is going on there or provide a resource that will help me better understand what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: @eg3 `char` is an *integral type* in Java. `char` + `int` is an `int`. You want the `char`. In other words, `'a' + 1` is `'b'` (as an `int`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I fixed my code and even upvoted your code. Could you please remove my downvote?

Comment: Or `for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)`.